# minimizing url of codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, url, routes

how can I minimize my codeigniter project url 
from

```
http://localhost/newsite/news/readnews/20
```

to

```
http://localhost/newsite/news/20
```

or

```
http://localhost/newsite/20
```

Comment: have you tried routing?

Comment: I have tried this $route['news/(:id)'] = "news/readnews/$1";

Comment: related: take a look at codeigniter blog tutorial for more about routes and also consider using "slugs" instead of numbers in the URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to create a route for this. Add the following to the route config file.

`$route['news/(:num)] = "/news/readnews/$1";`

Comment: what does it mean by " (:num) "

Comment: (:num) means that any integer/number can be used there as the param. It will not accept a string or anything else other than a number.

Comment: So if you go to `http://localhost/newsite/20` it shows `localhost/newsite/news/readnews/20` ?

Comment: I think you have a configuration issue elsewhere. Wampserver homepage should definitely not be showing up, even if the route was incorrect

Comment: no, it shows wampserver home page instead of my website for http://localhost/newsite/20

Comment: what kind of configuration issue?

Comment: Check my updated answer. I see the issue with my original answer

Comment: You have put my exact answer as it sits now into your route file? And when you go to localhost/newsite/news/20 it doesn't work?

Comment: I put that in route file. but for localhost/newsite/news/20, it shows a blank page and there is no news item

Comment: In your `/application/config/config.php` file, is your `$config['base_url'] = http://localhost/newsite/` ?

Comment: thanks for your time :) should it possible to remove news from 
 
localhost/newsite/news/20

Comment: Yes, if you change the route to: `$route['(:num)'] = "/news/readnews/$1";` it would make it so any time someone went to `localhost/newsite/20` they would see that news item. I don't personally recommend this because you would not be able to go to any other controller with it setup like this, unless you specifically set up routes for each controller. May actually work if you put a controller name instead of a number, but I'm not sure. Still, don't recommend it. If my answer helped you, please accept it!